# Jersey REST client post with authorization

Tags: jersey, http-post, authorization, jersey-client

I am using `Jersey 1.9` in my Java Spring MVC web application. I am trying to make a post request for which I have to set two header values - authorization and content type. I was able to successfully make the post using postman REST client. I have tried many solutions found online, but the response I get is 401-Authorization failed. Following is the code is the code I use:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
   Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/contacts?action_by=ACTION_BY_OWNER&api_key=tntkzy2drrmbwnhdv12s36vq");
WebResource.Builder builder = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
builder.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer 28ac08bc-58d5-426e-b811-3b1d1e505a9b");
ClientResponse responseMsg = webResource
     .post(ClientResponse.class, jsonString);
  responseMsg.getEntity(String.class);
```

Adding the postman screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Not very smart to post real credentials, if those are in fact real credentials. As far as your question, can you post an image of the Postman request?

Comment: @Paul Samsotha, those are not real credentials btw

Comment: I would try using `WebResource#queryParam` instead of putting the params in the Url string. I'm guessing those params are part of the authentication and are not being serialized correctly. Note that calling `queryParam` returns a new `WebResource`.

Comment: @Paul Samsotha - But would that really return 401 - Not Authorised

Comment: Isn't there an api key in the query param? Did you try it?

Comment: @Paul Samsotha - Still i am getting 401- Not Authorised. Code which I am using is  WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/contacts");
    ClientResponse responseMsg = webResource
      .queryParam("action_by", "ACTION_BY_OWNER")
      .queryParam("api_key", "key")
                 .post(ClientResponse.class, jsonString);
     responseMsg.getEntity(String.class);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166782/discussion-between-geo-thomas-and-paul-samsotha).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure then. It was just a guess. From what I can tell, your code looks just like the Postman request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I finally found what was missing in my case, based on the suggestions I got from the comments, I removed the query params from URL and added them as query params. ANd then added all query params to a multivalued map and used this multivalued map as the query param. My code was modified as follows:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
queryParams.add("action_by", "ACTION_BY_OWNER");
queryParams.add("api_key", apiKey);
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
ClientResponse responseMsg = webResource
.queryParams(queryParams)
.header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
.header("Authorization", "Bearer "+authorisationToken.trim())
.post(ClientResponse.class, jsonString);
responseMsg.getEntity(String.class);
```

Somehow when there are multiple query params, adding headers was not working, but when the params were added as a single multivalued map, everything works. Hope this helps someone.